# Check on two tables such that there is no anomalies in data

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables; one is `Delivery_order` as DO and the other one is `weight3` as w3 A DO is closed when its status='Received' but on the other hand a users also enter data for each DO in w3 table so I want to build a logic that if DO status='Received' then when user enter data in W3 it will get an error that DO is closed and the key between these tables is Contract_Number.

Can someone please tell me the logic or write me a query.

```
declare @latest date
declare @ContractNumber nvarchar(200)

select @latest=Max(DO.Time_stamp), @ContractNumber=DO.Contract_Number from Delivery_Order DO where DO_Status='Received' group by DO.Contract_Number

select distinct w3.ContractNo as contract_number,'After closing the DO data is entered!' AS Remarks
from weight3 w3 where 
 @latest<(select distinct MAX(w3.second_time) from weight3 w3 where w3.ContractNo=@ContractNumber) and w3.ContractNo=@ContractNumber
```

Comment: Without being able to see your data, we may not be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is that if there's an entered item in `Weight` table, it will give an 'Error' Remarks.

```
select case when coalesce(t1.contract_number, '') != '' then 'After closing the DO data is entered!' else 'success' end as remarks
 from 
    (select max(second_time) stime, contractno from weight3 w group by contractno) as t1
 left join 
    (select max(time_stamp) stime, contract_number 
    from delivery_order where status='Received' 
    group by contract_number) t2 on t2.contract_number = t1.ContractNo and t2.stime <  t1.stime
```

Comment: @METAL let me check it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create `instead of trigger` and check there your condition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckStatusOfDelivery 
ON weight3
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Delivery_order
          WHERE status = 'Received'
          AND contract_number IN (SELECT contract_number FROM inserted))
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Status is received!', 10, 1)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO weight3
      SELECT * FROM inserted
   END
END
```